# doFinal() javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption

Tags: encryption, aes

Sorry if this has been answered. I see several similar but not one I can identify as my issue.

I am getting the following error: 
    javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCEBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown Source)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal

```
public static String encryptAES(String key, String source) {
String encrypted = "";
try {  
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"); 
    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, iv); 
    byte[] bXml = source.getBytes("UTF8");
    byte[] enc = cipher.doFinal(bXml);
    encrypted = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(enc); 
} catch (Exception e) {  /** removed **/ }
return encrypted;
}
public static String decryptAES(String key, String source) {
String decrypted = "";
try {  
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");     
    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, iv); 
    byte[] dec = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(source); 
    byte[] bDecrypted = cipher.doFinal(dec);  /** Error occurs here **/
    decrypted = new String(bDecrypted, "UTF8");     
} catch (Exception e) {  /** removed **/ }  
return decrypted;
}
```

Comment: Could you replace the Sun inner class that performs the base 64 encoding and retry (Bouncy Castle has base 64 codec)? Note that you typically get this when the ciphertext is messed up, can you show how you treat the input/output of the methods? As a side note: you correctly use "UTF-8" as encoding for the plaintext, but not for the key (and a key should not be text).

Comment: I can replace the base 64 encoding and retry. I am not sure what you mean by "treat input/output". What would you like to see? On a side note, your comment caused me to find that there is a bug in the sun base64 encoding regarding EOL.

Comment: Interesting, but if you use that class against all Java regulations, you should expect trouble anyway. Now Java 8 has a [*public* class doing base 64](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html). If the error is in there as well, then you would have a point.

Comment: To test for faulty Base64, just have encryptAES return the byte[], and pass that in directly to decryptAES. If that works fine, then you know it's the Base64 encoding that is messing things up.

Comment: Failure results are in less than 1% of decryptions. So this has to be run against production, requiring separate VCS branch, server, etc...not so easy. Have coded this using a standard RFC 2045 implementation and will try as soon as production allows.

Comment: Base64 encoding is not the the issue. Error is still occurring after replacing with a standard RFC 2045 encoding. Further note, when AES fails, Blowfish also fails with same error. Can the source string be at issue somehow?